# Visualizing a graph

Tags: mathematical-software, applied-mathematics, graph-theory

I have a finite but huge metric graph with say 1000 vertices.
It comes say as 10000x10000 symmetric matrix filled by $0,1,\dots$ and $\infty$;
0's on the diagonal and $\infty$ is for pairs of vertices which are not connected.
(Most of the vertices have degree 3.)

I need to find a way to visualize this graph. 
I hope it will help me to see some patterns.

Is there any software which could help?
Say, I want to draw this graph in the space in a form which reflects its metric geometry.

Comment: Have you tried with Graphviz ? Or with Sage and with the plot3d() method ? Maybe your graph is too big to be drawn correctly with these tools anyway.

Comment: @Samuelle, no I did not, can it take the metric into account?

Comment: Where does this graph come from?

Comment: Btw, how about reading the answer on stackexchange to the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243616/visualization-tools-for-huge-graphs

Comment: @Per: the data comes from DNA

Answer (score 2):

Take reciprocals of the off-diagonal entries and treat this as a weighted adjacency matrix.  Then use a spectral layout.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html). It can import data in various formats, and there is an [image](http://www.yworks.com/en/imageviewer.php?img=../img/ygucd/spc.png&album=ygucd&fs=1) on their web site of a graph with 13,500 nodes and 26,000 edges, which is much larger than your graph.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to export this graph into a format readable by [Gephi](http://gephi.github.io/). While I have never used it for weighted adjacency matrices, it could be worth trying out.